# Is there a restrain on the total number of proper classes strictly smaller than the universe in variants of MK?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

In an old discussion thread at [sci.math](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/TwHPQaXRHs8%5B1-25%5D), Herman Rubin said:

"

> There exist models where all proper classes have the same cardinality;
> i.e., the universe is equinumerous with the class of ordinal numbers.
>
> There exist models where there are proper classes which are neither
> larger nor smaller than the class of all ordinal numbers.
>
> I am almost certain that there exist models with proper classes
> strictly larger than the class of all ordinal numbers, and all
> comparable.

"

On the other hand Asaf Karagila in a comment to this [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350786/is-there-a-model-of-mk-having-as-many-small-proper-classes-as-sets-are-there) to MO, have said:

"

> in ZF we can at least prove that every subset of $V_\kappa$ is an
> element of it, or maps onto $\kappa$.

" ($\kappa$ is meant to be inaccessible).

I take that to mean in absence of choice [since its stated in ZF alone]. Now in some sense $V_\kappa$ can be viewed as being the standard model of MK.

Clearly the second and third of Rubin's statements indicate the existence of a model of a variant of MK\NBG in which there do exist a proper class that is strictly less in size than $V$ namely the class $\small \sf [ON]$ of all ordinal numbers (that are sets of course).

I'm interested in the last of Rubin's statements. He said "all being comparable". I don't know if that entails choice [not global of course].

In the same referred [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/TwHPQaXRHs8%5B1-25%5D) Aatu Koskensilta answeres to the third of Rubin's statements by:

"

> Using the consistency of ZFC + "there is an inaccessible" (and
> standard well known independence results) it's easy to show there are
> such models. As noted, by some tweaking we can remove the inessential
> inaccessible, bringing us back to ZFC and MK in terms of consistency
> strength.

"

> Questions:
>
> 1. What are the models of those variants of MK in which there are proper classes of sizes strictly smaller than the universe $V$ of all sets, that are closest to the standard model of MK. Provided that the total number of proper classes in them is higher than that of sets.
> 2. Is there a restrain on the total number of such proper classes (i.e. strictly smaller than $V$) in such models.
> 3. Can those models satisfy choice for *sets*.